# HTML using a PHP script

Tags: php, html, grep

im new in php programming and ive a problem recently. I have 1 html page with a Search Box and a php script using for grep in a specific file on local host. This is what i want, when a user type string of char and click on enter that send a POST to modify my php var $contents_list, and grep all filename where the string is found.

```js
<?php

$contents_list = $_POST['search'];
$path = "/my/directory/used/for/grep";

$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
$compteur = 0;

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir) as $filename => $file) {
    $fd = fopen($file,'r');
    if($fd) {
        while(!feof($fd)) {
            $line = fgets($fd);
            foreach($contents_list as $content) {
                if(strpos($line, $content) != false) {
$compteur+=1;
                    echo "\n".$compteur. "  :  " . $filename. "  :  \n"."\n=========================================================================\n";
                }
            }         
        }
    }
    fclose($fd);
}

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
       </head>

<body>
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="search" name="search">
</form>
</body>
```

And when i go to my html page and type text in searchbar, that redirect me to my php script "localhost/test.php" and i have 500 internal error.

---

So I want:

To see result of the php script on the same html page, but i dont know how to do that :/

And if the previous filename return was same like previous result, dont print it, to avoid double result.

---

I hope its clear and youve understand what i want to do, so thanks for the people who want to help me    <3

Comment: if you want to stay on the page while the browser sending requests to server in the background, that is [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: okay so iavent error in my code?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:

- Combine the code into the single `index.php` file for simplicity
- Separate logic for search and output to achieve clean separation of duties
- Add helper text such as `nothing found` or `enter text`

`index.php` content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
  </form>

<?php
// Check if the form was submitted.
if (isset($_POST['search']) && (strlen($_POST['search'])) > 0) {

  $search_line = $_POST['search'];
  $path = "/my/directory/used/for/grep";

  $dir_content = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

  // Array to store results.
  $results = [];

  // Iterate through directories and files.
  foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_content) as $filename => $file) {
    $fd = fopen($file, 'r');
    if ($fd) {
      while (!feof($fd)) {
        $file_line = fgets($fd);
        if (strpos($file_line, $search_line) !== FALSE) {
          $results[] = $filename;
        }
      }
      fclose($fd);
    }
  }

  // Output result.
  echo "<pre>";
  if ($results) {
    foreach ($results as $index => $result) {
      echo ($index + 1) . " :: $result\n";
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "Nothing found!";
  }
  echo "</pre>";
}
else {
  // When nothing to search.
  echo "<pre>Enter something to search.</pre>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot youve resolve my problem, and do you think its possible to code a php searchbox, and when i type a string in, script will grep to all my database on my server(phpmyadmin) and return the database, and the columns name and the line?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. 

First of all, your database is probably `mysql` or `mariadb`, not `phpmysql`. 
Secondly, you would need to replace `scanning files` part with `query database`. You can find examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp